# Controlling music from phone only

Tags: music, htc-one, headphones

I have a HTC One m8. I am extremely annoyed by my headphones, they're about 2 years old and only when they're plugged in do they skip the songs I'm listening to on their own. The headphones are Skullcandy Titan if that helps. The mic area is cracked and probably the cause of my frustrations. I am looking for a short term solution to my problem by disabling that feature somehow and only controlling my music by going directly to the app in using to listen to music (I use Google play, Spotify, Tidal, Beats Music and Sound cloud. Looking occurs with all apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fix your problem: download [Headset Button Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kober.headset&hl=en) (trial), it allows you to override all the headset button functions, override what they do. With that in mind, set ALL button functions to "Disabled". This will prevent any skip tracks, previous tracks, or pauses generated by cracked mic.

Hope that helps